# How can I reload a mapquest map without refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, mapquest

Im using the traffic layer that is available with mapquest, here is the function Im using:

```
    function displayTrafficMap(lati,long,trafficdiv) {

    var options={

            elt:document.getElementById(trafficdiv), 
            zoom:10,
            latLng:{lat: lati,lng: long}, 
            mtype:'map',
            bestFitMargin:0,
            zoomOnDoubleClick:true

    };

    window.map = new MQA.TileMap(options);

    MQA.withModule('zoomcontrol3','viewcontrol3','traffictogglecontrol', 'shapes', function()  {

        var ttc = new MQA.TrafficToggleControl();
        var vwc = new MQA.ViewControl3();
        var zc = new MQA.LargeZoomControl3();

        window.map.addControl( zc , new MQA.MapCornerPlacement( MQA.MapCorner.TOP_RIGHT,  new MQA.Size(5,40)));
        window.map.addControl( vwc , new MQA.MapCornerPlacement(MQA.MapCorner.TOP_RIGHT));
        window.map.addControl( ttc , new MQA.MapCornerPlacement(MQA.MapCorner.TOP_RIGHT));

        ttc.toggle();

    });

}
```

When the page loads I load this function like so:

```
<script>window.onload = function() { displayTrafficMap(latitude,longitude,'trafficmap'); }</script>
```

This works fine, but how do I call this function again with new latitude and longitude without having to refresh the page? I tried this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="displayTrafficMap(newlat,newlon,'trafficmap');return false;">
```

But nothing happens. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears my answer was lacking, hopefully this will provide more information on the solution to the question. To confirm the question, I am using mapquest to display a map with traffic conditions on it. How do I update the maps lat/lon without having to refresh the page? Below is the entire script I use, including using jquery, hope this gives more of the answer someone might be looking for:

```
var traffic_map;

function displayTrafficMap(lati,long) {

    var options={

            elt:document.getElementById('trafficmap'), 
            zoom:10,
            latLng:{lat: lati,lng: long}, 
            mtype:'map',
            bestFitMargin:0,
            zoomOnDoubleClick:true

    };

    traffic_map = new MQA.TileMap(options);

    MQA.withModule('zoomcontrol3','viewcontrol3','traffictogglecontrol', 'shapes', function()  {

        var ttc = new MQA.TrafficToggleControl();
        var vwc = new MQA.ViewControl3();
        var zc = new MQA.LargeZoomControl3();

        traffic_map.addControl( zc , new MQA.MapCornerPlacement( MQA.MapCorner.TOP_RIGHT,  new MQA.Size(5,40)));
        traffic_map.addControl( vwc , new MQA.MapCornerPlacement(MQA.MapCorner.TOP_RIGHT));
        traffic_map.addControl( ttc , new MQA.MapCornerPlacement(MQA.MapCorner.TOP_RIGHT));

        ttc.toggle();

    });

}

function changeTrafficMap(lati,long)
{

    traffic_map.setCenter({lat: lati,lng: long});

}

//We run the display map function right away to load the map
displayTrafficMap(trafficlat,trafficlon);

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#traffic_areas').bind('change', function(ev) {

        //We get the id for the area that was selected
        var areaid = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({

            url:"/traffic.php?aid=" + areaid,
            type:"GET",
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data) {

                //First we change the current map view location
                changeTrafficMap(data.lat,data.lon);

            }

        });

    });

});
```

The ajax call is calling a php script called traffic.php, that script connects to my database to grab the lat/lon I assigned to the areaid that is being passed via the drop down selection.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @jzworkman - I disagree.  There's room for improvement, certainly, on describing this solution completely.  But if it's a solution to the problem, it should be an answer, not editted into the question.  As far as I understand, [partial answers are acceptable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144452/is-it-okay-to-put-partial-answers), though obviously not ideal.

Comment: I guess I just figured as a self answer(same poster as the question) you could either close the question(as is is very specific and not likely to help another case) or give more detail to the answer that it may be useful in the future.  As it is, it doesn't really give a lot of use as a reference for future users.

Comment: Hopefully this will help people in the future. I would like to mention no one attempted to help me with a solution on this so I really didnt figure it would be an issue with the original answer. I thought adding it would help someone in the future, but again hope the updated answer gives a more detailed description on what I did to resolve my issue.